# how can i detect special symbols from pdf/image?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

http://www.builditsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/578x551xGDT_TypesCharacteristicsSymbols.png.pagespeed.ic.I-zS47cHfO.png

i want to detect symbols in above image , i tried several text extractor api online they are detecting text but not special symbols like those in above image,
i have tried [tesseract ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) library in java eclipse,still the same result.

can some one suggest how can i achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

You could develop your own model with enough labelled inputs using any of the Deep Learning frameworks like TF, PyTorch or even the pytesseract.

Read here : [https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-text-recognition-ocr-using-tesseract-and-opencv/]

I am doubtful if you could find a pre-trained model though.